# To use gapi.client.drive.files.insert or to use gapi.client.request for everything

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am trying to understand how best to access the Google Drive using client side Javascript. I wrote some test code to insert a new file having only the metadata. I found an example that used this code:

```
var request = gapi.client.request({
   'path': '/drive/v2/files',
   'method': 'POST',
   'body': {
      "title" : "Meta File 1.json",
      "mimeType" : "application/json",
      "description" : "This is a test of creating a metafile"
      }
   });
```

The above code worked fine, but it doesn't use gapi.client.drive.files.insert. So I searched stackoverflow and tried the code below:

```
var mydata = {};
mydata.title = "Meta File using Insert.json";
mydata.mimeType = "application/json";
mydata.description = "We are using insert to create a new file, but only the metadata.";

var request = gapi.client.drive.files.insert( {'resource': mydata} );
```

This code works fine also, so my question is which should I use? Is there any reason to use the various api calls like files.insert, or should I always use gapi.client.request for everything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually have three choices ...

1. gapi..request (your first option)
2. gapi..files (your second option)
3. plain javascript (ie. not using any google library at all)

Underlying each option is the same HTTP request/response so the functionality is the same. It probably comes down to personal preference and trust.

Personal preference
Do you want to understand what your app is doing all the way down the stack, or do you prefer to use a high level abstraction?

Trust,
The Google JS library is closed source, and is updated arbitrarily, and without warning. So if the G engineers break it (as they have done in the past), you have nowhere to turn and your app is down until it is fixed. Provided you have a mainstream use case, it should get fixed, but there is no guarantee. If you are using an edge case (perhaps an unusual nodejs configuration, or idiosyncratic browser) you could be left high and dry.

Personally I use option 1 on the basis that if the Drive team add a new feature to the API, I can use it straight away, without waiting for the JS Client Library maintainer to support it too. It also makes debugging easier since what goes over the wire is directly related to my code.

Now that Drive supports CORS uploads, I'm migrating from option 1 to option 3. Option 3 is also the only viable option if you want to build chrome extensions or packaged apps.

Comment: This was an excellent answer. The fact that you you enumerated the different types and discussed about short/long-term use cases was helpful.

Also `gapi.client.drive.files` does not work anymore. I often get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined`. 

Do you have any resources how I would write code if I wanted to try your #3 plain javascript option?

Comment: Thanks. Reading my answer back, it's a bit outdated. Since I use Angular. I decided to write my own library github.com/pinoyyid/ngGAPI to wrap option 3 with Angular promises. It's working well for me.